Viable to sort IEEE754 floats by MSB?
I've been doing some low-level bit manipulation, and ended up creating an algorithm that sorts 64-bit floats by octets of descending significance (LE = 7 -> 0; BE = 0 -> 7) as a byproduct. When logging the output, I expected an arbitrary order. However, somewhat to my surprise, they were sorted (with the caveat that negative numbers are placed after positive)! Here's an example of random floats (-50, 50) being implicitly sorted:
[
  4.2217695176666155,
  4.6478025698022165,
  25.500103628472857,
  26.819343028582594,
  43.402122471148246,
  44.150586938484324,
  -12.313937254813531,
  -21.429343402208257,
  -27.2049115791126,
  -38.48913575841195
]

I was wondering to what extent this output is a coincidence or computational truth, because it would be convenient to rely on this data being sorted. I also recognize that this sounds very similar to radix sort, but as mentioned before I understand the mantissa to be arbitrary in relation to numeric order.
Here is the TS class that exhibits this behavior and below is how I am testing it.
const ns = new NumberSet();

for (let i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    ns.add(100 * Math.random() - 50);
}

for (let n of ns) console.log(n);


@user24714692 I have added it to the original post.

You should also test it with numbers that are less than one. Signed zeroes =0 VS -0 will obviously be a long way apart but the rest should be in monotonic order (smallest magnitude first). You can play around with it on IEEE754 converter to see why this works.

Your code looks pretty clean. I'd also post a question in here, if I were you.

@MartinBrown I can confirm that the pattern breaks down for numbers less than 0. That alone is enough to disuade me from relying on this behavior, but it would still be interesting to hear ideas about what is causing this.

@MartinBrown Nevermind, I somehow misread the output. Over 5 runs, Math.random() * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) appears to be sorted in the same manner.

@user24714692 Cross-posting complete, thanks for the reccomendation: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/292921/typescript-number-set

You can "compare" floats using lexicographic ordering, i.e., treat the stored bits as a string or an unsigned integer, if you do the following:

Check for NaN. If so, the procedure doesn't apply. Abort. (NaN's don't compare to others--including themselves--the comparison result is always false whether it's equality or greater/less than etc.)
If negative-zero, then treat it as positive 0 (i.e., flip the sign bit)
If negative, flip all the bits (including the sign bit)
Otherwise, flip the sign bit only (leave other bits the same)

The above assumes you don't have any NaN values, hence step-1 above. Provided that is the case, and you apply the above transformation, then you can compare two floats as unsigned integer values (or lexicographically if you like), and the result will be the correct ordering of the original floats. This is true even in the presence of infinities, positive or negative, leading to correct IEEE754 compliant comparison semantics.
In particular, the reason float exponents are stored biased is precisely because you can do this trick, i.e., comparisons become easier. What you are doing essentially exploits this structure, and thus the output coming out as it does in your case isn't surprising.

Thank you so much! I'll have to see if keeping track of NaNs and flipping -0 (does anyone have a way to detect this? JS says 0 === -0) is faster than native sort. Good to have confirmation :)

We ignore the sign of 0 in step 2, precisely because 0 == -0. I wouldn't expect this trick to be any faster than native sort though; because most likely the comparison itself gets compiled down to a HW instruction, which will run pretty fast. (See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcom:fcomp:fcompp)

Assuming OP is ok with sorting "-NaN" < -inf < negative number < -0 < +0 < positive number < +inf < "+NaN", they can skip steps 1 and 2.

@chtz Indeed. But this also will distinguish NaN's themselves: Differing payloads will lead to different orderings of them. Probably not a concern, but something to keep in mind.

If the language used allows bit manipulation, and assuming no NAN's, then you can treat float similar to sign + magnitude numbers, and use these bit operations without any conditional statements to convert sign + magnitude to unsigned integer and back. Note that this treats -0.0 as less than +0.0. Using C syntax:
a[i] ^= ((uint32_t)((int32_t)( a[i])>>31)>>1)|0x80000000ul;  /* convert to unsigned */

Perform unsigned integer sort (such as radix sort).
a[i] ^= ((uint32_t)((int32_t)(~a[i])>>31)>>1)|0x80000000ul;  /* convert back */

